# If $\operatorname{Im} A = \operatorname{Im }A^T$, is it necessary that $A = A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Suppose $A$ is a square $n \times n \ (n > 3)$ matrix. Is it true that if $\operatorname{Im}A = \operatorname{Im}A^T$ then $A = A^T$?

My attempt: $\operatorname{Im}A^T = (\ker A)^{\bot}$ hence $ImA = (\ker A)^{\bot}$ hence $\operatorname{Im}A \ \oplus \ \ker A = \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\forall \ x \rightarrow x = x_1 + x_2$ where $x_1 \in \operatorname{Im}A, x_2 \in \ker A$. Then consider $x^TAy \ (x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n) \ x^TAy = (x_1+x_2)^TA(y_1+y_2) = x_1^TAy_1 + x_1^TAy_2 + x_2^TAy_1+x_2^TAy_2 = x_1^TAy_1$ because the second and the fourth terms are zero according to $y_2 \in \ker A$ and the third term is zero because $Ay_1 \in \operatorname{Im}A$ but $x_2 \in \ker A$. Now consider $x^TA^Ty = (x_1 + x_2)^TA^T(y_1+y_2) = (Ax_1)^Ty_1 + (Ax_1)^Ty_2 + (Ax_2)^Ty_1 + (Ax_2)^Ty_2 = (Ax_1)^Ty_1$ because the last two terms are zero because $x_2 \in \ker A$ and the second term is zero because $Ax_1 \in \operatorname{Im}A$ while $y_2 \in \ker A$ hence $\forall \ x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n \ x^TAy = x^TA^Ty$ therefore $A = A^T$

Is it a correct proof? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is not true.

For any invertible $3\times 3$ matrix, we have $\operatorname{Im}A = \Bbb R^3$, and its transpose is also invertible, so it necessarily has the same image. This does *not* mean that every invertible matrix is symmetric.

For posterity, the mistake was in the last line. Yes, $x^TAy = x_1^TAy_1$ and $x^TA^Ty = x_1^TA^Ty = (Ax_1)^Ty$, but that doesn't mean that $x_1^TAy_1= (Ax_1)^Ty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've found a mistake in my considerations.

Comment: @DF You can post an answer to your question pointing out the mistake for future viewers - or editing it in directly in your question